# Find sum and average in a single query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query which shows sum and average. The sum has some complex calculations. My query is almost like:

```
SELECT (SELECT a + b - c * d FROM master) AS sum,
       (SELECT a + b - c * d FROM master) / 5 AS avg
FROM master;
```

How can I reduce code by putting the sum (which I is already calculated) into a variable (or some other way) to find the average using it.

I  am using Oracle SQL developer.

Comment: Whats the purpose of test table here?

Comment: @Gaj Jack Sparrow sent it to settle his debt.

Comment: That query unlikely work s. There is `a.id = b.id` in the `WHERE` clause, but a relation named `a` was never introduced.

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is a generic SQL tool that can connect to several different databases. But it's fair to assume that you are using the Oracle database then

Comment: I am not that good at sql, I was just trying to express my need with an example. What I mean is to use the 'sum' which is selected, to find the average

Comment: Show sample data and expected output to avoid confusion. Only in text format, no images.

Comment: You could improve your question by adding sample data as text to the question together with desired result.

Comment: I have edited the example given in the question

Comment: That the total is divided by a fixed number 5 to get an average seems odd to me. Perhaps using the SUM & AVG functions could be useful here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following

```
SELECT m.col as SUM, m.col/5 as AVG  
FROM (SELECT (a + b - c * d) col FROM master) m ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're probably after something like:

```
WITH sum_info AS (SELECT id, a + b - c * d total
                  FROM   master)
SELECT t.id,
       si.total,
       si.total/5 average
FROM   test t
       INNER JOIN sum_info si ON t.id = si.id;
```

I'm assuming that master.id is a unique column here. Without more details on your actual problem (e.g. sample input data and expected output data), it's very difficult to know if this actually answers your question. Only you can help us to help you...

Answer (score 0):

I'd use

```
SELECT sum(term) as sum,
       avg(term) as avg
  FROM (SELECT (a + b - c * d) AS term FROM master);
```

The '5' in your query is the number of rows, right? If not, you can use

```
SELECT sum(term) as sum,
       sum(term)/count(*) as avg
  FROM (SELECT (a + b - c * d) AS term FROM master);
```